# Refresh Only template Grails

Tags: list, grails, grails-orm, gsp

I have a list.gsp which loads a template .
Actually the template contains  which loads the data from the domain class.
Every 10 seconds I want to refresh the template only, so that it gets latest data from the db. How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this but all of them require Ajax.  I'll give one example:

Suppose the following HTML:

```
<div class="content">

  ... other content here

  <div id="template">
     <g:render template="someTemplate" ... />
  </div>

  ... other content here

</div>
```

Then this javascript:

```
setInterval(refreshTemplateEveryTenSeconds, 10000);

function refreshTemplateEveryTenSeconds() {
   $('#template').load("/some/server/resource"); 
}
```

See the [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) docs for more info on this.

Obviously, if you're not using jQuery then modify to do the ajax call as your technology would suggest.  But this gives you a general idea of how you might approach the problem.

Comment: Thanks! That makes Sense. But here my _template.gsp has list.gsp code that shows data from the database. What do i use in load("") call? @Gregg

Comment: Did you read the docs for the load() function?  You can pass in parameters.